# Unable to delete notebooks from my project

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-local

I have a project in DSX Local and I have added some Jupyter notebooks. When I go to see my assets and click on delete (via the 3-dot menu at the right of the screen) it asks me whether I want to delete my notebook. When I confirm my screen shows "Deleting" for about a minute. Then it returns an error at the top of my screen: "There was an error deleting the notebook." and my notebook is still in the list of assets. I can even still open my Jupyter notebook afterwards.

How can I remove my notebooks?

Comment: have you tried what is suggested in the support site (https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/local/limitations.html#kernel-must-be-running-for-the-notebook-to-be-deleted):   
If you are unable to delete a notebook due to a "There was an error deleting the notebook." error, restart the kernel and retry the deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was able to load my notebook in Jupyter to start the kernel. When I went back to my asset list I could then see a kernel was started as I now had an option to stop the kernel. So it looked like my kernel was not started at all at the time I wanted to delete the notebook.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be due to the kernel not running when you tried to delete the notebook.  Can you try to start the kernel and then delete the notebook again?  This is known limitation documented here:
https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/local/limitations.html#kernel-must-be-running-for-the-notebook-to-be-deleted

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was able to load my notebook in Jupyter to start the kernel. When I went back to my asset list I could then see a kernel was started as I now had an option to stop the kernel. So it looked like my kernel was not started at all at the time I wanted to delete the notebook.